# Multiple definitions error while compiling

Tags: c, compilation

When I compile I get multiple definitions error, for example

> multiple definition of `__data_start'
>   multiple definition of `_init'

I read around the forum and in the answers they talk about makefiles but I'm not using makefiles to compile, just gcc.

My compilation statement is:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -O -o textbuffer.c textbuffer
```

Comment: and your compilation statement is?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I edited it in

Comment: if this is the solution to your question, i'll remove the comment and post as an answer instead. You can accept that to mark the question solved. Thanks.

Comment: It was the solution, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your compilation statement

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -O -o textbuffer.c textbuffer
```

As per the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options), `-o` switch is used to denote the output file

> -o file
>
> Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

So, essentiallly, your compilation statement should look like

```
 gcc -Wall -Werror -O textbuffer.c -o textbuffer
```

Answer (score 0):

**use : in declaration **

```
#ifndef
#define __data_start
#define __init
#endif
```

Comment: Can you explain? where is the :?